# a tag is not working properly with webpack and fancy box

Tags: webpack, fancybox

I have an *a tag* with an *img tag* in it. But when I look at the html in the console, the a tag href attribute is still the same and the src in img tag modified. I don't know what to do to make these two tags address the same.

```
<a href="./assets/gallery/laptop.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="some test">
   <img src="./assets/gallery/laptop.jpg" />
</a>
```

However, in development the href in *a tag* will remain as is and only the *img src* modified.

```
<a href="./assets/gallery/laptop.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="some text">
   <img src="imgs/laptop.762c6e8306d856f0dfba44f4a985aec1.jpg">
</a>
```

#### this is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/template.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            //JS
            {
                test: [/.js$/],
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            data: '@import "./scss/variables";',
                            includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'imgs'
                    }
                }
            },

            //JQUERY
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'jQuery'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: '$'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling out the file into a variable. I assume you are using JSX:

```js
const img = require('./assets/gallery/laptop.jpg')

<a href={img} data-fancybox="images" data-caption="some test">
   <img src={img} />
</a>
```